# Typescript: passing additional parameters to callback function

Tags: typescript, callback

I want to pass a params to a callback function. Here is my function:

```
    let func = function(el, index){
    if(el.id === myId) return index;
    }
    arr = [obj1, obj2, obj4, ...];
    arr.filter(func);
```

How can I pass `myId` to the callback in this case ? thank in advance!

Comment: Create a "higher-order function", `arr.filter(funcCreator(myId))`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you please explain a bit more how to do this ?

Comment: I'd recommend searching for information about HOFs in JavaScript, there are many existing resources on that.

Answer (score -1):

**Try this:**

```
let myId = 1 // for example
let arr = [obj1, obj2, obj4, ...];
arr.filter((el, index) => {
  if(el.id === myId) return index;
} )
```

Comment: thank for your answer. The issue is that my function is in another file and just imported.